# Export error with addon

Tags: materials, export, add-on

Im trying to export a model for the Euro Truck Simulator 2 game with the Blender2SCS addon and I get the following error, any help?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.72\scripts\addons\io_scene
_scs\__init__.py", line 1951, in execute
    error = export_scs.save(filepath, origin_path, root_object, self.copy_textur
es, int(self.pmg_version))
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.72\scripts\addons\io_scene
_scs\export_scs.py", line 27, in save
    status, ob = export_pmd.save(exportpath, originpath, root_ob, copy_textures)

  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.72\scripts\addons\io_scene
_scs\export_pmd.py", line 305, in save
    pmd.write(f, exportpath, originpath, copy_tex)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.72\scripts\addons\io_scene
_scs\export_pmd.py", line 267, in write
    ret_ob = exp_mat.write(copy_tex)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.72\scripts\addons\io_scene
_scs\export_mat.py", line 91, in write
    for option in self.__options.keys():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'

location: <unknown location>:-1

location: <unknown location>:-1
```

Answer (score 2):

The addon seems to be broken due to api changes in Blender, either use the addons [bug tracker](http://blender2scs.tk/news-feed/report-error) or try an older version of Blender that is compatible. According to the video tutorials version 2.66 was used.